# Handling two type of user authentication in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm developing an application that has two types of users. depending on which type of user is logged into the system, it should allow access to different pages in the nav-bar. with one type of user, I can handle it. but with two types of users, I get lost. please anyone can help me

in the auth.service I handle log-in for both types of users. user types are admin and employee

auth.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Admin } from './admin.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from './employee.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private Token: string;
  private isAuthenticatedAsAdmin = false;

  private isAuthenticatedAsEmployee = false;

  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();

  getAdminsToken() {
    return this.Token;
  }

  getAuthStatuesListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

 
  getIsAuthAsAdmin() {
    return this.isAuthenticatedAsAdmin;
  }


  getIsAuthAsEmployee(){
    return this.isAuthenticatedAsEmployee;
  }


  signInAdmin(
    username: string,
    password: string
  ) {
    const admin: Admin = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      id: null,
    };
    this.http.post<{ accessToken: string }>('http://localhost:3000/admin/admin-signin', admin)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.accessToken;
        this.Token = token;
        if (token) {
          this.isAuthenticatedAsAdmin = true;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
        }
      });
  }    

  signInEmployee(usename: string, password: string){
    const employee: Employee ={ 
      id:null,
      username: usename,
      password: password,
      salt: null
    };
    this.http.post<{accessToken: string}>('http://localhost:3000/auth/signin', employee)
    .subscribe(response=>{
      const tokenE = response.accessToken;
      this.Token =tokenE;
      if(tokenE){
        this.isAuthenticatedAsEmployee = true;
        this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      }
    })
  }
  
}
```

in a component, which checks for both type of users, likewise bellow,

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  userIsAuthenticatedAsAdmin =false;
  private authListenerSubs: Subscription;

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authListenerSubs = this.authservice
    .getAuthStatuesListener().subscribe(isAuthenticatedAsAdmin =>{
      this.userIsAuthenticatedAsAdmin = isAuthenticatedAsAdmin;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.authListenerSubs.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

in `ngOnInit`, the above code handle it only one type of user(above code handle it for admin). what should I do to handle both types of users, any help please.

Comment: If at a time only one type of user(either admin or employee) can login, then why to use two different properties to store token and handle separate flags to check employee or admin?

Comment: @Tejeshree -one tag can be used. I'll fix it. but how can I make sure who has logged in without two separate flags

Comment: You can use isAuthenticatedAsAdmin flag - if true it means it is admin, and set this false in employee block, which will implicate that this is employee and not admin. Similarly, the listener can be set to either true or false, would suggest to change the name of listener in that case.

Comment: @Tejeshree -sorry i've provided less data, there is a third user which doesn't log in to the system. therefore, when no one is logged in, that is considering as the third user.

Comment: if I use a number instead of boolean(`private isAuthenticated: number`), does it will help me to verify the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code and change component as per your need:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Admin } from './admin.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from './employee.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export enum userTypeEnum {
    ADMIN = 0,
    EMPLOYEE = 1,
    OTHER = 2
}
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private Token: string;

  private authStatusListener = new Subject<number>();

  getToken() {
    return this.Token;
  }

  getAuthStatuesListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  signInAdmin(
    username: string,
    password: string
  ) {
    const admin: Admin = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      id: null,
    };
    this.http.post<{ accessToken: string }>('http://localhost:3000/admin/admin-signin', admin)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.accessToken;
        this.Token = token;
        if (token) {
          this.authStatusListener.next(userTypeEnum.ADMIN);
        }
      });
  }    

  signInEmployee(usename: string, password: string){
    const employee: Employee ={ 
      id:null,
      username: usename,
      password: password,
      salt: null
    };
    this.http.post<{accessToken: string}>('http://localhost:3000/auth/signin', employee)
    .subscribe(response=>{
      const tokenE = response.accessToken;
      this.Token =tokenE;
      if(tokenE){
        this.authStatusListener.next(userTypeEnum.EMPLOYEE);
      }
    })
  }
  
}
```

In component, you will have to handle based on number you receive:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  userType: number = 2; // 2 for other type of user by default
  private authListenerSubs: Subscription;

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authListenerSubs = this.authservice
    .getAuthStatuesListener().subscribe(isAuthenticatedAsAdmin =>{
      this.userType = isAuthenticatedAsAdmin;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.authListenerSubs.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```